# Android library projects

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a libray android pakage i included a external jar (apache.commons) i marked the project as library.

I create a new android project add library under andriod tab add project under source tab build it and it builds fine. As soon as i call something out of that class i get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

What is going on. I tried adding uses-library but then i get  shared library not found.

My permissions is the same as the library project. There is no activities in library project.

thanks

Comment: Did you check you have imported it at the top of your java file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Library project are, basically, 'inclusion of the src and res files'.
Nothing more...
So included jar should be included in all the project...

At least, it is how I've seen things while working with Android Library Project